# Optimizing only certain variables of the model working with TensorFlow Estimator API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I need to freeze parts of my model and train only certain variables. Now, with the low-level API, I can just pass `var_list` to the `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize` method. But, when I use a TensorFlow Estimator, I can only pass the optimizer itself which is then used to minimize the loss inside the Estimator inner loop.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to define a custom optimizer and override the `Optimizer.minimize` method. Something like this:

```py
def minimize(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Inside...")
    if not kwargs['var_list']:
       kwargs['var_list'] = self.var_list

    return super(MyOptimizer, self).minimize(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, I expected to see the "Inside..." phrase to be printed on the screen each training step; especially when I'm seeing the model being trained just fine. This kinda shows me that my `minimize` function is being completely ignored and I can't seem to figure out why.

So, is it even correct to override `minimize` or is there a better way of doing this with Estimators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make custom estimator by specifying model_fn function

```
    def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
      logits = model_architecture(features)
      loss = loss_function(logits, labels)
      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = optimizer
        train_op = ontimizer.minimize(loss=loss, 
                                      global_step=global_step,
                                      var_list=variables_to_minimize)

      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
```